# What CMS should I use site that has a members only section

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I am helping out a friend and rebuilding her dance business site.

Requirements:
- site owner friendly CMS for updates
- Prefer a free cms
- main site and a few pages will be for new/potential clients
- members only section where she can post updates instead of having to email a news letter.
- an additional page or 2 exclusive to members where videos can be posted for at home practice

I am thinking wordpress may be a great option for this.  Any tutorials out there to help with the initial build of a member only section?  I want to make sure I lock down the member section properly.

I am hoping to also generate an email each time a post is made in the members only section.  Also use categories in the members only section to generate emails to members with corresponding tags that an update was made.

Is this attainable?

I am open to other CMS platforms but they must be responsive, free, and easy for the site owner to update.

Answer (score 0):

Go for wordpress. As you are a starter use subscription / membership plugin to manage the member setting that you desire, and for email you can use newsletter plugins (both free adn paid) . Hope this helps :)
And for the final question : no wordpress is the easiest one out there